# How to find error messages from Linux init.d/rc.d scripts?

Tags: linux, logging, init.d, rc.d

In Linux, I've written some scripts to be executed during boot and played around with the various ways of installing them. For larger scripts I'll put in `/etc/init.d` and link the appropriate `/etc/rc.d/rc?.d` runlevels. For smaller scripts, I'll append to `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`. This process seems to be running smoothly.

Now I've tweaked one of my scripts and it is failing. I'm having a heck of a time diagnosing it because I can't seem to capture the error output. I've checked `/var/log/messages` and poked around the rest of `/var/log` but can't find anything of use.

Does anyone know:

1. are these error messages automatically captured somewhere?
2. if not, how can I capture the stdout/stderr from my init.d scripts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/321926/59925

Comment: If you go to a more modern distribution with systemd it will handle that for you and allow to journal log messages of each service.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. No - they go to **STDOUT** (if you use `echo`) or **STDERR** (if you use `echo >&2`).
2. Your scripts have to write to logs and/or syslog on their own (your distribution might contain some *init.d* functions that might help there - add your distribution to your question).

If you go for logs look for the `tee` command. If you go for syslog look at `logger`. You can combine them in any way you want to.

Answer (score 9):

Write a wrapper script that calls your script and redirects the output to a files

```
#!/bin/bash

    /path/to/your/script &>/path/to/logfile
```

Answer (score 7):

You could make a function to echo the message to both the screen and to syslog, something like this:

```
LOGGER="/usr/bin/logger -t $myScript"    # check the location of logger for your system

myEcho () {
    echo "$1"
    $LOGGER "$1"
}
```

You could also put that into a separate file and include it into your scripts with

```
#!/bin/bash
myScript=$(basename $0)
[ -r /myFunctions/myecho ] && . /myFunctions/myecho
```

Comment: Thanks, this is closer to what I was looking for. I know how to redirect I/O but I didn't know how to call into the logger.

Comment: Is `[ -r ... ]` a test to check if it exists?

Comment: Yes, check if the file is readable.

Answer (score 6):

Messages from init scripts are generally not captured anywhere. Thus, you need to implement a way to do it yourself. A good idea is to use `logger` to send all output to syslog. This example will send stdout and stderr to syslog:

```
exec 1> >(logger -s -t $(basename $0)) 2>&1
```

I found it in this great article: http://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2014/09/09/redirecting-bash-script-output-to-syslog/.